# How to read text file without column name using spark Dataframe in java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using `Spark` `DataFrame` to read a text file and each row is delimited by one space, such as follows (path: `d:/data/kmeans_data.txt`):

```
0.0 0.0 0.0
0.1 0.1 0.1
0.2 0.2 0.2
9.0 9.0 9.0
9.1 9.1 9.1
9.2 9.2 9.2
```

I am try to use `DataFrame` to read this text file:

```
Dataset<Row> dataset = spark.read().text("file:/d:/data/kmeans_data.txt");
```

However, it calls an `IllegalArgumentException`:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "features" does not exist.
>   Available fields: value
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(StructType.scala:267)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(StructType.scala:267)
>       at scala.collection.MapLike$class.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:128)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractMap.getOrElse(Map.scala:59)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.apply(StructType.scala:266)
>       at org.apache.spark.ml.util.SchemaUtils$.checkColumnType(SchemaUtils.scala:40)
>       at org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeansParams$class.validateAndTransformSchema(KMeans.scala:93)
>       at org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans.validateAndTransformSchema(KMeans.scala:254)
>       at org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans.transformSchema(KMeans.scala:340)
>       at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage.transformSchema(Pipeline.scala:74)
>       at org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans.fit(KMeans.scala:305)
>       at ml.dataframe.clustering.SPKMeans.main(SPKMeans.java:32)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

How to read text file using spark `DataFrame` in java? If there are no column names and label column, whether we should create one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your input data.

You would like to load your text file into spark as a CSV file with delimiter is a space. 
You can also load data without headers with option `header`

As the following example code.

```
  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("learning").setMaster("local[2]")

  val session = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate()
    val schema =  DataTypes.createStructType(Array(
        DataTypes.createStructField("f1",DataTypes.DoubleType,false),
        DataTypes.createStructField("f2",DataTypes.DoubleType,false),
        DataTypes.createStructField("f3",DataTypes.DoubleType,false)
      ))

  val df = session.read
    .format("csv")
    .option("header", false)
    .option("delimiter", " ")
    .schema(schema)
    .load("file:/d:/data/kmeans_data.txt")
```

Comment: I know that the file can be converted into csv file. What I am wondering is that whether can I read text file without header using `DataFrame`?

Comment: @DuFei Yes. You can. That's what my answer is doing.